# Set counter in exam class to a count based on the first set of questions

Tags: counters, exam

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{s}
\setcounter{s}{0}
\newtotcounter{e}
\setcounter{e}{0}
\newcommand{\squestion}[0]{\stepcounter{s}\question}
\newcommand{\equestion}[0]{\stepcounter{e}\question}


\begin{document}

\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Short questions}}    
There are \total{s}\ short questions. %display the number of short questions.

\begin{questions}
\squestion
This is the first short question.
\squestion
This is the second short question.
\end{questions}


\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Essay questions}}
There are \total{e}\ essay questions. %display the number of essay questions.

\begin{questions}
\setcounter{question}{\total{s}}  % Set the counter to start with 3
\equestion
This is the first essay question.
\equestion
This is the second essay question.
\equestion
This is the third essay question.
\equestion
This is the fourth essay question.
\end{questions}

For the record there is a total of \numquestions\ questions.

\end{document}
```

I would like to know why this line of code `\setcounter{question}{\total{s}}` is not working. Why `\total{s}` is not replaced by `2`?

Comment: `\total` will print `??` if it is called on the first compilation --> you're trying to put `??` as a counter value. This must fail of course

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How can I fix this please

Answer (score 1):

Since `\total{foo}` will print `??` on the first compilation run the output of `\total{foo}` can't be fed into a `\setcounter` statement.

However, it is possible to extract the real counter value by using `\value{foo@totc}` or in a wrapper command `\extractcntrvalue`. The first call in a compilation will provide a wrong value, but this is no real issue since in most cases a `LaTeX` document has to be run at least twice, the next call will provide the correct counter value and store it to `question` etc.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{totcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extractcntrvalue}[1]{%
  \value{#1@totc}%
}
\makeatother



\newtotcounter{s}
\setcounter{s}{0}
\newtotcounter{e}
\setcounter{e}{0}
\newcommand{\squestion}[0]{\stepcounter{s}\question}
\newcommand{\equestion}[0]{\stepcounter{e}\question}





\begin{document}
\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Short questions}}    
There are \total{s}\ short questions. %display the number of short questions.

\begin{questions}
\squestion
This is the first short question.
\squestion
This is the second short question.
\end{questions}


\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Essay questions}}
There are \total{e}\ essay questions. %display the number of essay questions.

\begin{questions}
  \setcounter{question}{\extractcntrvalue{s}}  % Set the counter to start with 3
  \equestion
This is the first essay question.
\equestion
This is the second essay question.
\equestion
This is the third essay question.
\equestion
This is the fourth essay question.
\end{questions}

For the record there is a total of \numquestions\ questions.

\end{document}
```