# Change number to word

Tags: exam, count

Referring to the question below
[Set counter in exam class to a count based on the first set of questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348733/set-counter-in-exam-class-to-a-count-based-on-the-first-set-of-questions)

I would like to change the answer for this. 
There are `\total{s}\` short questions.

From There are 2 short questions 
to There are TWO short questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `fmtcount` defines the command `\numberstring{counter}`.  Adding this to the answer in [Set counter in exam class to a count based on the first set of questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348733/set-counter-in-exam-class-to-a-count-based-on-the-first-set-of-questions), we get

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extractcntrvalue}[1]{%
  \value{#1@totc}%
}
\makeatother



\newtotcounter{s}
\setcounter{s}{0}
\newtotcounter{e}
\setcounter{e}{0}
\newcommand{\squestion}[0]{\stepcounter{s}\question}
\newcommand{\equestion}[0]{\stepcounter{e}\question}





\begin{document}
\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Short questions}}    
There are \total{s}\ short questions. %display the number of short questions.

\begin{questions}
\squestion
This is the first short question.
\squestion
This is the second short question.
\end{questions}


\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Essay questions}}
There are \total{e}\ essay questions. %display the number of essay questions.

\begin{questions}
  \setcounter{question}{\extractcntrvalue{s}}  % Set the counter to start with 3
  \equestion
This is the first essay question.
\equestion
This is the second essay question.
\equestion
This is the third essay question.
\equestion
This is the fourth essay question.
\end{questions}

For the record there is a total of \numberstring{question} questions.

\end{document}
```

Note that if you want to extract the information from a "total" counter, this will not work, because `totcount` counters are not counters in the LaTeX sense.

However, we can use the command `\extractcntrvalue` defined above together with `\numeberstringnum` command:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extractcntrvalue}[1]{%
  \value{#1@totc}%
}

\makeatother



\newtotcounter{s}
\setcounter{s}{0}
\newtotcounter{e}
\setcounter{e}{0}
\newcommand{\squestion}[0]{\stepcounter{s}\question}
\newcommand{\equestion}[0]{\stepcounter{e}\question}





\begin{document}
\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Short questions}}    
There are \numberstringnum{\extractcntrvalue{s}} short questions. %display the number of short questions.

\begin{questions}
\squestion
This is the first short question.
\squestion
This is the second short question.
\end{questions}


\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Essay questions}}
There are \numberstringnum{\extractcntrvalue{e}} essay questions. %display the number of essay questions.

\begin{questions}
  \setcounter{question}{\extractcntrvalue{s}}  % Set the counter to start with 3
  \equestion
This is the first essay question.
\equestion
This is the second essay question.
\equestion
This is the third essay question.
\equestion
This is the fourth essay question.
\end{questions}

For the record there is a total of \numberstring{question} questions.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, but why I can't use \value{s} alone with out \extractcntrvalue{s}

Comment: I think it is discussed in the linked question